# Python if and else print condition

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

If an integer is divisible by 3, print "Hi"

If it is divisible by 7, print "Bye"

If it is divisible by both 3 and 7, print "HiBye"

As of now I have tried:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print "Hi"
    if i % 7 == 0:
        print "Bye"
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
        print "HiBye"
    else: 
        print i
```

But my numbers are repeated. i.e. this is the output I get.

```
1
2
Hi
3
4
5
Hi
6
Bye
7
8
Hi
9
10
11
Hi
12
13
Bye
14
Hi
15
16
17
Hi
18
19
20
Hi
Bye
HiBye
```

As you can see, the 3 is repeated again. I think the mistake is in the

```
else:
    print i
```

statement

Comment: I think you are missing the `elif` statement

Comment: Well, what does your code do for `21`? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: the keyword you are looking for is `elif`

Comment: @cricket_007: Oh, my bad!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `elif` instead of `if`, and test for the *3 and 7* case *first*:

```
if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
    print "HiBye"
elif i % 3 == 0:
    print "Hi"
elif i % 7 == 0:
    print "Bye"
else: 
    print i
```

You used *independent* `if` statements. Each `if` statement is tested and their block is executed, regardless of what other `if` statements your code may execute before or after. `elif` blocks, however, are attached to their `if` statement and Python will only ever execute *one of the blocks*, the first one whose condition is true.

So in the above `if..elif..elif..else` series of tests, if `i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0` is True, *none of the other branches will be executed*, including the `else` branch.

Now the output looks like:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 22):
...     if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
...         print "HiBye"
...     elif i % 3 == 0:
...         print "Hi"
...     elif i % 7 == 0:
...         print "Bye"
...     else:
...         print i
...
1
2
Hi
4
5
Hi
Bye
8
Hi
10
11
Hi
13
Bye
Hi
16
17
Hi
19
20
HiBye
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you code to

```
for i in range(1,100):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
        print "HiBye"
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print "Hi"
    elif i % 7 == 0:
        print "Bye"
    else: 
        print i
```

Because otherwise it will individually look at each **if** statement and when its on 3 for example it does the first part of code but when it tries`if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:`it will be false so it prints i

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, these are the conditions:
1) if the number is divisible by 3 print "Hi"
2) if the number is divisible by 7 print "Bye"
4) if the number is divisible by 3 and 7 print "HiBye"
5) if none of the above conditions are met, print the number.

```
for i in range(1,100):
if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
    print "HiBye"
elif i % 3 == 0:
    print "Hi"
elif i % 7 == 0:
    print "Bye"

elif i % 3 != 0 and i % 7!= 0:
    print i
```

This code works for the above conditions. It states them explicitly and forces the logic.

Comment: I changed it to fix the problem

Comment: Why the last `elif`? Why not just use `else`?

Comment: Just to make sure the condition is met. In these cases, I find it better to be explicit. It's really the order that python is iterating and passing through the numbers that matters.

Comment: It's overly verbose and redundant. You are making Python do extra work that you already tested for.

Comment: Yeah.. I know. But I found that building in some redundancy when trying to solve a problem helps figure out what python is doing.